# How can I fix pitch black self-shadows?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shadow

I started a new project and all the self-shadows look like in the image below.

[image: ToDarkShadows.png]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Place another light in the scene?

Comment: thats the problem i dont want to place lights all over the place! i am searching for something like a slider that conrols how dark the selfshadows are!

Comment: Change the ambient light of the scene in `Window > Lighting`. Or check [here](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1492979/shadows-are-too-dark.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the direction of your shadows. I think you are using a directional light. If you want your scene to be equally lit or dim with some factor. `Ambient Light` is the type of light you have to use along with your current Directional or other types of light in your scene. By balancing out between Ambient Light intensity and your scene lights you can get the results you are aiming for.

For detailed documentation:

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/lighting-ambient-light.html

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/lighting-window.html

Answer (score 0):

You can change the ambient light of the scene in `Window > Lighting > Settings > Environment Light`.

I got this from this question on the Unity forum: [Shadows Are Too Dark](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1492979/shadows-are-too-dark.html).